# Not able to share data in state store among sub-topologies of a Kafka Stream App

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Note: it's an invalid question.  Please ignore.

I have a KSA listens to two topics (two sub-topologies), one (sub-topology A) writes into the state store and the other (sub-topology B) reads from the state store.

Write

```
...
  stream
      .mapValues(v -> new Version(v.getHeader().getOccurredAt().getSeconds(), v.getVersion().getValue()))
      .groupByKey()
      .aggregate(
        () -> new Version(0,0),
        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue.getTimestamp() > newValue.getTimestamp() ? aggValue : newValue,
      Materialized.<String, AgentVersion, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(conf.versionStoreName())
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
        .withValueSerde(Serdes.serdeFrom(
          new Version.Serializer(), new Version.Deserializer())));
```

Read

```
 ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Version> getVersionStore() {
  return app().store(conf.versionStoreName(), QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
}
```

However, I found that B is not able to get the data written by A (A can get the date correctly).
Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

By design, sub-topologies are isolated from each other. If you want to give access from one sub-topology to a store from another sub-topology, you need to connect both sub-topologies into a single one. For example by adding the corresponding store to a processor/transformer.

Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#stream-partitions-and-tasks